# Having trouble with LINQ Select in VB.NET and C# differences

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

When using VB.NET I can do the following:

```
Public Function GetUser(ByVal ID as Integer) As User
    Dim dc As New YesEntities()
    Return (From u in dc.Users Where u.ID = ID).Single()
End Function
```

And on my .aspx/.vbhtml page I can access the user's department name like this:

Dim DepartmentName as String = new User().GetUser(12).Department.Name

However, in C# when I do this:

```
public User GetUser(int ID)
{
    YesEntities dc = new YesEntities();
    return (from u in dc.Userswhere u.ID == ID Select u).Single();
}
```

I cannot because I get this error:

A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'YesModel.User' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Departments'.

### UPDATE

I used departments to keep it simple for the initial example so sorry for the upcoming confusion but it's actually "User" ==> "MobileCarrier" that I'm having the issue - more detailed information below:

Here's my EF
http://screencast.com/t/ORIhVfygk

and its properties
http://screencast.com/t/G0bERcZ1q7

**User.cs**

```
namespace Yes.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {

        YesEntities dc = new YesEntities();

        public IEnumerable<User> GetAll(bool IsUnsubscribed = false)
        {
            return (from u in dc.Users where u.IsUnsubscribed = IsUnsubscribed orderby u.LastName, u.FirstName select u);
        }
    }
}
```

**AdminUserController.cs**

```
namespace Yes.Controllers
{
    public class AdminUserController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /AdminUser/
        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<User> users = new User().GetAll();
            return View(users);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Yes.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}

<h2>Users</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Options</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Cell Number</th>
        <th>Mobile Carrier</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>StateProvince</th>
        <th>IsApproved</th>
        <th>CreateDate</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
            <td>@item.FirstName</td>
            <td>@item.LastName</td>
            <td>@item.EmailAddress</td>
            <td>@item.PhoneNumber</td>
            <td>@item.CellNumber</td>
            <td>@(item.MobileCarrier!=null ? item.MobileCarrier.Name : "")</td>
            <td>@item.IsMale</td>
            <td>@item.City</td>
            <td>@item.StateProvince</td>
            <td>@item.IsApproved</td>
            <td>@String.Format("{0:g}", item.CreateDate)</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with that method, as both are equivalent. You have a mapping error in the EF model.

Comment: Hmm - I bet you are right.  DepartmentID (ForeignKey) is nullable and one of the records does not have an entry so I bet I need to check for null.

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't leave off the "select u" in C# when I can leave it off in VB.NET?

Comment: yes, it's simply the C# syntax. Both languages have their rules and syntax, and C# just does it that way. Why? Probably to have the same pattern throughout code, you'll need the select statement anyway in more complicated cases, so they required it to directly see it selects the current object into the sequence.

Comment: I checked for null in my MVC View before displaying the Department.Name but still get the same error.  Is there somewhere in the EF model that I need to explicitly "Include" Departments into the query?  I see a lot of examples that do this:  dc.Users.Include("Department").ToList() but that doesn't seem to work either (and it's not strongly-types either so I don't like that approach - feels like cheating).

Comment: I would have to see the mapping to tell you if and where something is wrong, but I think that might be too much for a question on this page. Are you using the same model you use in the vb example or are you generating a new one? from the same database? same foreign keys? same settings for eager/deferred loading?

Comment: Ground up in C# using EF in MVC for this project and I'm just pulling from extensive background knowledge of VB.NET using Linq-to-SQL in WebForms.  Starting from scratch in the C# and two new frameworks all the same time is daunting.

Comment: I'll try to break my code down to something more basic so I can isolate exactly where the issue is.  Your answer is correct in that it's not the method itself so I'll mark it as such.  thanks!

Comment: if you want, I can have a look at it, you should be able to piece a mailadress together using my name and a popular search engine (I'm really curious what the problem is about).

Comment: Everything seems normal to me, no idea what is happening there.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'm going to add a dummy table that's related to the Users table like MobileCarriers is but not make it nullable and see if it works fine in that scenario.  If so, then at least I'll know it has something to do with that.

Comment: So, when I made MobileCarrierID in the Users table non-nullable, all of the rest of the code works fine.